# fetch records in from has_many table rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models with below associations :-

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties_room_type
  has_many :rate_plan_mappings, through: :properties_room_type
end

class PropertiesRoomType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rate_plan_mappings
  belongs_to :property
end

class RatePlanMapping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :properties_room_type
end
```

I have **rate_plan_id** in **rate_plan_mappings** table So my motive is to create hash like :-

{property_id => [rate_plan_id]} as property has_many rate_plan_mappings}

```
example:

 {1 => [22,23], 2 => [25,29,30], 3 => [9,7,6]}
```

as 1,2,3 are property_id and and array is rate_plan_id corresponding to it.

How can I join the table and make this type of structure from above association.

I can do one to one with each loop but that's not the correct method :-

```
prop_hash = {}
prop_all = Property.all
prop_all.each do |property|
  prop_hash.merge!("#{property.id}" => [property.rate_plan_mappings.where(active: true).pluck(:rate_plan_id).uniq])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
# query data
arr = RatePlanMapping.joins(properties_room_type: :property).pluck("properties.id", "rate_plan_mappings.rate_plan_id")

# Group arr by property_id
hash = arr.group_by { |sub_arr| sub_arr[0] }

# Modify Hash to desired structure
modified_hash = {}

hash.each do |k, arr|
  modified_hash[k] = [ arr.flatten.uniq - [ k ] ].flatten
end
```

For e.g. for

```
arr = [
  [2, 10],
  [2, 20],
  [1, 21],
  [2, 22],
  [3, 23]
]
```

wherein `arr[N][0]` is the `property_id` and `arr[N][1]` is the `rate_plan_id`
the `modified_hash` should hold `{2=>[10, 20, 22], 1=>[21], 3=>[23]}`

Thanks.